# Value of a alternating series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I compute the value of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: This way: $1-\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint :

$$e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+ \ldots$$

What would happen if we put $x=-1$?

Comment: If $x=-1$ then it will alternate. So this is the same as the series?

Comment: @AlimTeacher Did you put $x=-1$? If you did then you'll clearly be able to see the pattern by pulling out '$-$'.

Comment: Yes I understand thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\exp(-1) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} = \ldots = 1 - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $ (-1)^n = -1(-1)^{n+1}$